# Regex / awk / etc for scanning my source code for translations

Tags: regex, unix, grep, translate

I'd like to scan my source for certain lines such as:

```
$obj->setLabel('output this text')->someOtherMethod(etc);
```

or:

```
$this->view->title = "I want this text";
```

Obviously the code is PHP. I'm using Zend Framework. That doesn't really matter.

I'm running linux and understand pipes. I'm guessing I could pipe:

```
grep --include=*.php -R 'setLabel(' .
```

into awk or whatever. I just want the each of the "one or more" characters output on it's own line surrounded by quotes, terminated by a comma. CSV translation files are not far off then.

I only expect to search for one pattern at a time. So first I'd get all the "Labels" etc.

**note:**
I know of POedit, etc. I'm using CSV files for static UI translations. I'm not going to change that. They need to be editable by a 3rd party who just wants to use "Excel" (shudder...)

This is what I ended up using:

```
grep -oh --include=*.php -R -E "setLabel\('[^']*'\)" . > labels.txt
```

And then removing the unwanted "setLabel(" and ")" in a text editor. However, I'm very keen for a cleaner one-liner. Oh... There is also code-golf. I should ask those guys...

Comment: I've now got this: grep -oh --include=*.php -R -e "setLabel('.*')" .

Comment: and now this: grep -oh --include=*.php -R -E "setLabel\('[^)]*'\)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `find` and `sed`:

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec sed -ne "s/.*setLabel('\([^']\+\)').*/\1/p" {} \;
```

and

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' -exec sed -ne "s/.*view->title = \"\([^\"]\+\)\".*/\1/p" {} \;
```

Comment: Genius! Thanks! Does sed have the same regex capabilities as grep? What do the curly braces and ending slash do?

Comment: Yes, `sed` uses standard basic POSIX regex, like `grep`. The curly braces are replaced with the file names matched by the `find` expression so these files are passed to `sed`. The `\;` is here to mark the end of the command passed to `-exec` in the `find` expression. On recent versions of `find`, you can also use `\+` instead of `\;` to pass all files at once to `sed` instead of each file one by one. This is usually faster, provided the command (such as `sed`) supports taking several files as input.

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks for the follow up explanation.

Comment: `awk`, too, allows matching on patterns.  General rule of thumb: if you're thinking of using `grep` and then piping that into `sed` or `awk`, drop the `grep` because you're wasting resources for no gain.

Comment: Yep indeed, and drop the `cat` in 95% of cases, too ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Ruby(1.9+)

say you want to search for `setLabel`

```
$ ruby -ne 'puts $_.scan(/.*setLabel\(\047(.[^)]*)\047/)' file
output this text
```

say you want to search for `view-title`

```
$ ruby -ne 'puts $_.scan(/.*view->title\s+=\s+\042(.[^"]*)\042/)' file
I want this text
```

Comment: Interesting, but sorry, I'm not going to install Ruby just for this. It really needs to be basic GNU/Linux CLI stuff.